# 2 Objects in model.setAttribute method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Basically I have a Form which I have an Object 'Sighting' being made, when being requesting the specific URL to make a sighting. Although, In the form I have another object Which I would like in a  tag to be populated from a database. This select tag basically gets all the 'pests' from a database and populates them. My controller is setting adding 2 attributes like this, I am not sure if it is the correct way of doing it, or will one object overwrite another when submitting it.

My Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping("/sighting")
public String makeSighting(Model model, Principal principal) {

    List<Pest> pests = pestsService.getPests();
    model.addAttribute("pests", pests);
    model.addAttribute("sighting", new Sighting());

    return "sighting";
}
```

If you could help me out that would be great. If needed I will provide the code for the Form also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach. But you can define a single form backing object for your `form`:

```
class SightingForm {
Sighting sighting;
List<Pest> pests;
...
}
```

And this can be used to populate the `form` :

```
@RequestMapping("/sighting")
public String makeSighting(Model model, Principal principal) {

    List<Pest> pests = pestsService.getPests();
    SightingForm sightingForm = new SightingForm();
    sightingForm.setSighting(new Sighting());
    sightingForm.setPests(pests);

    model.addAttribute("sightingForm", sightingForm);

    return "sighting";
}
```

and in your JSP, use this single `sightingForm` as your form backing object:

```
<form:form id="form" action="${submitUrl}" modelAttribute="sightingForm" method="POST">
<form:input path="property" id="propertyId" />
...
</form:form>
```